# Ubuntu13.10 64 bit installed alongside windows 7 32bit doesn't boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 64-bit alongside windows 7 32-bit. (Windows installed first.)

The installation was successful, but when I restart it just goes directly to windows 7 without any sign of existence of Ubuntu.

I'm a beginner who just wanted to get familiar with Ubuntu, but now I'm disappointed with it. Someone told me the not booting problem is related to EFI, but now I'm scared to play with this boot stuff because my information might be totally lost.

How can I fix this boot problem and get to Ubuntu?

Comment: why have you installed windows 7 32 bits, but installed a 64 bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I didn't do that on purpose.I was using window 32 bit but the idea of using ubuntu crossed my mind,so I downloaded it (64 bit)and installed it.Do you think this is the problem????

Comment: No, that is not the problem. There is no reason you can't install a 64-bit Ubuntu (on a 64-bit machine) alongside a 32-bit Win7

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem,you can install `64 bit`Ubuntu along with `32 bit` windows but it must be a `64 bit machine`.Try the below steps to get back your ubuntu os without data loss.

- Log in into your windows 7 os.Download and install EasyBCD from [*`here`*.](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/EasyBCD-Download-45820.html)
- Under linux section add a boot entry for your Ubuntu Partition.
  And also add entry for your windows 7 partition.
- reboot

## Or

try [`boot-repair disk`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) .If it was a `64 bit`machine,you can download `64 bit version of boot-repair-disk`.

Comment: In the first method,should I choose  grub or grub2?and after choosing i should add two entry, one for windows and the other for linux(Am I right?). What next?should I go to edit boot menu?which one should I choose ?(there are  three:windows 7 and two of Neosmart

Comment: you choose grub2 bootloader for ubuntu.create two entry for windows and linux partition.To create a windows boot entry type the name as windows7 and correctly locate the windows 7 partition.To create ubuntu boot entry ,type the name as `ubuntu 13.10`,bootloader as `grub2`,and select the exact ubuntu partition.If there is any entries other than these please delete it.

Comment: I tried what you said,and now I have ubuntu 13.10 and windows  7 .But when it restarts and I choose ubuntu a two black page appear:  first one==  Initialize variable space(suddenly disappears)         second== Grub Dos 0.4.5c 2012........(something)                     .what should I do?              for now i try second method

Comment: please tell me how to work with this boot repair

Comment: once boot-repair-live cd is booted up,a dialog box appears and click on the `recommende repair` option.It will automatically reinstall your grub2 bootloader.

Comment: I tried the second method.It worked and I'm commenting in ubuntu.but I lost win7.It is not in my choices.when it boots I have two choices:ubuntu--- ubuntu something(i cant remeber) then  I choose ubuntu.while it's loading it says the win 7 not recognized 1you can wait 2 press s and go to ubuntu 3 fix the problem manually(and then goes to grub DOS.is there any hope?

Comment: any comment here?

Comment: please upload gparted screenshot,in `imgur.com` i will try to help.

Comment: excuse me,but how do I do that .what is gparted screenshot?

Comment: install gparted application in your ubuntu,by running `sudo apt-get install gparted`.After the installation completed,open it.Also install shutter software to take screenshot of opened gparted application.after taking the screenshot,upload the file to imgur.com,and post the link here.

Comment: One of my friends solved the problem.he just typed a command  update-grub or something !!